The uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+\sin x}$
How to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+\sin x}$ converges uniformly on $[0,+\infty)$?
That's what I got: $|f_n-0|=|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+\sin x}|\leq|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}-1}|$ and then I used Leibniz's test to show, that $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}-1}$ converges, but I guess that modul is destroying it. So maybe should I use Dirichlet criterion? If so, how to show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sin x}$ converges uniformly on $[0,+\infty)$?

You should start the sum at $n=2$ to avoid dividing by 0 when $\sin(x)=-1$.

Hint: $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sin x}|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-1}$.

@Mark Careful: $\sum_n 1/(\sqrt{n}-1)$ doesn't converge.

@RobertIsrael I know. The purpose of the hint was to answer the question OP asked in the last line. (after which he will be able to use Dirichlet's test)

Why I need it to use Dirichlet’s test? I just need to show its uniform convergent

@pueblo30 So maybe use the hint to prove uniform convergence? I want to give you the right direction, not to solve your homework.

Sure, I guess I’m just too bad in this topic, so I’m leaving it. Thanks anyway!

Typically in questions like this, try to eliminate $(-1)^n$ if possible, by dividing the terms into even and odd indices. The error function is $
E_N(x)=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+\sin x}
$. Therefore,
$$
E_{2N}(x)
{=
\sum_{n=2N}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+\sin x}
=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}+\sin x}+\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sin x}
\\=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}+\sin x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sin x}
\\=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2n}+\sin x)(\sqrt{2n+1}+\sin x)(\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n})}.
}
$$
Likewise,
$$
E_{2N-1}(x)
=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{(\sqrt{2n-1}+\sin x)(\sqrt{2n}+\sin x)(\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n})}.
$$
Now, both of $|E_{2N}(x)|$ and $|E_{2N-1}(x)|$ can be bounded by $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2n-1}-1)(\sqrt{2n}-1)(\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n})}$ for sufficiently large $N$, from which a proof of uniform convergence is achievable $\blacksquare$

Dear downvoter, care to demonstrate the error?
